# What is the PulseAudio virtual sink name for ALSA snd_pcm_open()

Tags: ubuntu, alsa, pulse-audio, open

I loaded a `PulseAudio` `module-null-sink`, when I set it as system default output device, the `ALSA` `snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, "default", SND_PCM_PLAYBACK, 0)`  can successfully open it. Now I need to directly open the virtual sink instead of setting it as default, which means I have to find the correct device name of that sink. Someone mentioned `asoundrc` or `asound.conf` files may contain all available devices for `ALSA`, but these files don't exit on my ubuntu. I also tried `aplay -L` to list all devices, turned out there're only hardware devices, no virtual sinks. The `pacmd list-sinks` gives information about virtual sink like:

```
* index: 4
    name:<Virtual_Sink_2>
    driver:<module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBLE_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    priority: 1000
    ......
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    ....
```

but <Virtual_Sink_2> didn't work, what is the correct `module-null-sink` name for ALSA opening? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pulse:DEVICE=Virtual_Sink_2`. It should work as long as the version (1.2.1 or later without being tampered) of the alsa-plugins package on your distro includes [this](https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-plugins/blob/master/pulse/50-pulseaudio.conf) as e.g. `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/50-pulseaudio.conf`.

Comment: The file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/50-pulseaudio.conf does exist, but ```pulse:DEVICE=Virtual_Sink_2``` as name parameter for `snd_pcm_open() still doesn't work. It gives error like: ```ALSA lib conf.c:4738:(snd_config_expand) Unknown parameters DEVICE=Virtual_Sink_2``` ```ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM pulse:DEVICE=Virtual_Sink_2``` ```ERROR: Can't open "default" PCM device. Operation not permitted```

Comment: @AlexLau Are you with something like Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? Compare the content of your `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/50-pulseaudio.conf` with https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-plugins/blob/master/pulse/50-pulseaudio.conf

Comment: @AlexLau If they are different, use the one online as your `~/.asoundrc` or `/etc/asound.conf`

Comment: Yes the `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.d/50-pulseaudio.conf` is different from the online one, mine looks like: `pcm.pulse{type pulse hint{show on description "PulseAudio sound Server"} } ctl.pulse{ type pulse }`

Comment: I'm on a rare ubuntu16.04 distro, both `~/.asoundrc` and `/etc/asound.conf` don't exist.

Comment: @AlexLau Just create either of them with the content of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alsa-project/alsa-plugins/master/pulse/50-pulseaudio.conf

Comment: I've created `/etc/asound.conf` with content like: `pcm.pulse{ type pulse device Virtual_Sink_2} ctl.pulse{ type pulse device Virtual_Sink_2}` still not working.

Comment: @AlexLau Well, that is not what I've instructed you to do. What I meant is to literally just copy and paste the content from that link.

Comment: Yes I also tried that, makes no difference.

Comment: @AlexLau well perhaps you need a more updated alsa-plugins in full then. PPA or whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient reply, let me try that.